# Blazor Component paging

Tags: asp.net-core, components, paging, blazor

I am working on Blazor application and have a component showing list of records (retrieving from entity framework entity), wanted to know what would be best and easiest approach to implement paging on component.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Blazor you can pass your Page just as you would in MVC.

For a very simple sample, make the following changes to FetchData.razor :

```
@page "/fetchdata"
@page "/fetchdata/{PageNumber:int}"

... the HTML for the table...

<div>
    @for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        <span><a href="fetchdata/@i"> @i </a>|</span>         
    }
</div>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }

    private WeatherForecast[] forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (PageNumber < 1) PageNumber = 1;

        // adapt the service to take pageIndex, pageSize
        forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(PageNumber-1, 5);
    }
}
```

The pager is very crude, just 1 .. 5. There are components available that can do most of the markup and logic, google for "Blazor Pager component". I found [this one](https://gunnarpeipman.com/blazor-pager-component/) pretty quickly.

Comment: Thanks Henk Holterman & Ali Borjian, I tried combination of both the solution it worked like Charm...

Answer (score 6):

In Blazor you have full control over your DOM. As You are using EF so you can simply perform Skip and Take for your paging :

```
private int pageSize = 100;
private int pageNumber = 1;
```

in HTML :

```
for(int p = 1; p<= list.Count() / pageSize ; p++) {
<button type="button" @onclick="(e=>HandleChangePage(p))">@p</button>
}
```

Handle Change Page :

```
void HandleChangePage(int p) {
  pageNumber  = p;
  var page = list.Skip((p-1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
}
```

It's the easiest way to do paging, 
Now you can go ahead and create your paging list component 
Now you need to pass your list to the component as a parameter

```
[Parameter]
public List<ClassName> list {get;set;}
```

If you want to work with a generic list look at [Template context parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#template-context-parameters)

Comment: I'm not sure why this happens to me, but passing p to HandleChangePage is always the fully incremented value. I have to assign a new int and pass it in order to fix this issue, like so: int pageId = p; @onclick(() => HandleChangePage(pageId))

Comment: @GeorgiG See also https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10138

Comment: Also instead of `list.Count() / pageSize`, you should use `Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(list.Count() / Convert.ToDecimal(pageSize)))`

Answer (score 6):

I developed a generic paging component which uses an HTML table and is easily reusable.  Save this in it's own component razor named PagedList.razor:

```
@typeparam TItem

@if (!ListQuery.Any())
{
  <div class="none-indicator">(none)</div>
}
else
{
  @if (TotalPages() > 1)
  {
    <div class="pager-display">
      @if (CurrentPage == 1)
      {
        <button disabled>&laquo;</button>
        <button disabled>&lsaquo;</button>
      }
      else
      {
        <button @onclick="@MoveFirst" title="Move First">&laquo;</button>
        <button @onclick="@MoveBack" title="Move Back">&lsaquo;</button>
      }
      <span>@CurrentPage of @TotalPages() </span>
      @if (!AtLastPage())
      {
        <button @onclick="@MoveNext" title="Move Next">&rsaquo;</button>
        <button @onclick="@MoveLast" title="Move Last">&raquo;</button>
      }
      else
      {
        <button disabled>&rsaquo;</button>
        <button disabled>&raquo;</button>
      }
    </div>
  }

  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      @HeaderDisplay
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach (TItem item in CurrentDisplay)
      {
        @ItemDisplay(item)
      }
    </tbody>
  </table>
}

@code {
  [Parameter]
  public IQueryable<TItem> ListQuery { get; set; }
  [Parameter]
  public RenderFragment HeaderDisplay { get; set; }
  [Parameter]
  public RenderFragment<TItem> ItemDisplay { get; set; }
  [Parameter]
  public int ItemsPerPage { get; set; } = 10;

  private int CurrentPage = 1;
  private List<TItem> CurrentDisplay;
  private int TotalCount;

  protected override void OnParametersSet()
  {
    UpdateDisplay();
    TotalCount = ListQuery.Count();
  }

  private void UpdateDisplay()
  {
    CurrentDisplay = ListQuery.Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * ItemsPerPage).Take(ItemsPerPage).ToList();
  }

  private bool AtLastPage()
  {
    return CurrentPage >= TotalPages();
  }

  private int TotalPages()
  {
    return Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(TotalCount / Convert.ToDecimal(ItemsPerPage)));
  }

  private void MoveFirst()
  {
    CurrentPage = 1;
    UpdateDisplay();
  }

  private void MoveBack()
  {
    CurrentPage--;
    UpdateDisplay();
  }

  private void MoveNext()
  {
    CurrentPage++;
    UpdateDisplay();
  }

  private void MoveLast()
  {
    CurrentPage = TotalPages();
    UpdateDisplay();
  }

}
```

Here's an example of it being used:

```
<PagedList ListQuery="People">
  <HeaderDisplay>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Title</th>
    </tr>
  </HeaderDisplay>
  <ItemDisplay>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="People/Edit/@(context.ID)">Edit</a></td>
      <td>@context.FirstName</td>
      <td>@context.LastName</td>         
      <td>@context.Title</td>
    </tr>
  </ItemDisplay>
</PagedList>

@code {
  private IQueryable<Person> People;

  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
    People = DatabaseContext.Person.Where(p => ...)
  }
}
```

Comment: You are using DatabaseContext directly in client code, in terms of "security" that can be a problem right?

Comment: Microsoft doesn't mention that being an issue:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: if its shared between client, the client can be changed and they have access to context in order to delete entries etc..

Comment: If you can provide a link to an article explaining that, I'd be interested in seeing it.